# Flutter debug runs on one iOS 14 device, but won't run on another iOS 14 device

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-debug

I have two iOS devices, iPhone 8 and iPhone 12 mini, both runs iOS 14.4.

Flutter debug works normally on iPhone 8, but it won't launch app on iPhone 12 mini. It will hang on launch screen and then just exit.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in myproject...
Launching lib/main.dart on XX iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: XYXYXYXYX
Xcode build done.                                           117,9s
Error launching application on XX iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I can start debugging from XCode on both devices, but even after successfull start from XCode, debug won't work from flutter next time when I run `flutter run` on iPhone 12 mini.

Runnin `flutter run --release` also works OK.

This is what I get at the end when I run `flutter run --verbose`

```
...
...
Application launched on the device. Waiting for observatory port.
[+30020 ms] Installing and launching... (completed in 61,6s)
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on Sheriff iPhone.
[   +5 ms] "flutter run" took 372.990ms.
[   +7 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:617:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1080:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:931:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:230:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:70:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[  +85 ms] (lldb) process detach
[ +228 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 230ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[  +56 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

flutter doctor

```
# flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale sr-Latn-RS)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Local network connection is allowed for the app on iPhone 12 mini.

I have tried all kinds of flutter clean, pod install, deleting DeriverdData, restarting iOS device etc. but it didn't work.

What am I missing here?